# laravel 4.1- default value of dropdown is blank

Tags: php, laravel

I am trying to display some data from database with dropdown. I can get all data needed from a table named "classes" and they are displayed, but the problem is that the default vale, which I get from an other table "cars" that is the las value inserted for a specific car, it is blank.

```
{{ Form::select('class', $class ,$v->class,array('class' => 'form-control') ) }}
```

`$v` is the array where I get default value. When I use `var_dump($v->class)` it shows the value , but when I set it at a select option it is blank.
carController.php

```
public function edit($id) {
            $data['values'] = DB::table('cars')
                    ->join('classes', 'cars.class', '=', 'classes.id')
                    ->select('cars.*', 'classes.class')
                    ->where('cars.id', '=', $id)
                    ->get();
            $data['class'] = DB::table('classes')->orderBy('class', 'asc')->distinct()->lists('class', 'id');
            return View::make('pages.edit', $data);
```

edit.blade.php

```
@foreach ($values as $v) 
{{ var_dump($v->class); }}
{{ var_dump($class); }}
    @endforeach
```

result:

```
string 'CABRIOLET & FUN' (length=15)

array (size=10)
  10 => null
  8 => string 'CABRIOLET & FUN' (length=15)
  3 => string 'Compact' (length=7)
  2 => string 'Ekonomike' (length=9)
  1 => string 'Mini' (length=4)
  4 => string 'Premium & Luksoze' (length=17)
  5 => string 'SUV (CROSSOVER)' (length=15)
  6 => string 'SUV (OFF ROAD)' (length=14)
  7 => string 'SUV (PICK UP)' (length=13)
  9 => string 'VAN & MINIVAN' (length=13)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know how looks your $class and $v->class, but check with doc example:

```
echo Form::select('size', array('L' => 'Large', 'S' => 'Small'), 'S');
```

Comment: Could you paste var_dump for $class and $v->class (from file with your select)?

Comment: And result for var_dump($class) ?

Comment: In "default" option you must put id of your "class" like '8' for 'CABRIOLET & FUN': {{ Form::select('class', $class ,$v->class_id,array('class' => 'form-control') ) }} or something like this (ofc you must create $v->class_id if you don't have it)

Comment: the problem is that at array values I have 2 id (one of table "cars" and one of table classes) $v->id gives the id of cars not of class